# Dr. Racket - Professor sent us this code; unsure of what it is doing. Want clarification

Tags: ascii, racket

The code segment is this...

```
(define (my-make-list n)
  (build-list n (λ (x) (build-string 50 (λ (x) (integer->char (+ 65 (make-random-integer)))))))
)
```

obviously this creates the my-make-list function. The function then builds a list composed of 50 character strings, where I am lost is what is the lambda doing and what's the significance of the +65?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tonumber function (tonumber ‘(one two three) --> 123](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700896/tonumber-function-tonumber-one-two-three-123)

Comment: `65` is the `ASCII` for uppercase 'A'.

Comment: I'm assuming that would be what the (integer->char) is doing, but why +65 to the random number?

Comment: @GoombaJoe I'd guess that in this implementation, characters from integers below 65 are non-alphabetic characters (e.g., control codes, punctuation, etc.).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor you are correct in accordance to the ascii table.

Comment: Not all languages are guaranteed to use ASCII, so I didn't want to presume about Racket (but that should be checkable in the docs).  It's not clear what make-random-integer does though.  Can't it return a big number *n* such that *n+65* is above the ASCII range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Edper commented, 65 is the value of [**`ASCII`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character `A`. Adding 1 to the value will give the value of character `B` (66). Adding 2 will give the value for `C` (67), ... 25 for `Z` (90).

So, assuming `make-random-integer` generate random number between 0 and 25, the `my-make-list` returns *n* random upper-case strings (50-characters long).

```
> (require racket/math)
> (define (my-make-list n)
  (build-list n (λ (x) (build-string 50 (λ (x) (integer->char (+ 65 (make-random-integer))))))))
> (define (make-random-integer) (exact-floor (* (random) 26)))
> (my-make-list 1)
'("BXXCBXVQEERWLETALMZZSVSVGIEXPYLKQNXTYLASRKLCNOONRN")
> (my-make-list 3)
'("EAUHIHEEKIKQFDWSUXOLAFKBEYCDZKDRQNMGTHKMUNIUGTMRSD"
  "GUMWLTOYHCZMQVCTZHIIPRMGXFOKNYAWEVOVSLCWXLFCIYNHKT"
  "PBJDEFPLZHTCQEXIVEAGEFPTFXCRDWJVXIIHDJUCNYLPJAYWCA")
```